# How to make Mac OS X more convenient for a person with low vision?

Tags: macos, ui, accessibility, customization

Is there any way to adjust Mac OS X GUI to have larger buttons, larger texts, larger and more distinctive window borders?

The long story.

I'm a software developer, I'm using Windows as my main working and entertainment machine. After Microsoft's move to Windows 10 (which treats customers as guinea pigs and which has already failed on me a few times with BSODs and micro freezes without ability to track their source) I decided that I'd like to have a reliable machine for my work and leisure, so I started exploring Mac OS X world.

I have low vision since birth. I don't use magnifier tools or screen readers, but I have set my 24" monitor to a lower resolution and I have been creating custom Windows themes since Windows 98 to adjust colors to be more distinctive here and there (the default Windows high contrast themes are an overkill, my eyes get hurt, but other themes seem too dull). In this aspect, Windows 8 was a real pleasure for me with its flatness - no glows, no shadows or 3D effects, thick window borders, large close/min/max buttons so I can focus my mouse on them really fast... I just adjusted the highlight colors to be more distinct, and it was good to go. (And Windows Vista was a real nightmare with its distracting effects and barely visible light blue item selection color).

Now I have been trying Mac OS X for a few days on my friend's machine. In general, I find that I can get used to its workflow and organization. But I have problems with its style.

I like that El Capitan looks more flat than previous Mac OS X GUI themes. But still there is not enough distinctive (or someone might say - distracting) colors for me to be able to focus fast on desired areas with my mouse. I can't be as productive on Mac OS X as I could on Windows just because I cannot adjust its GUI to my specific vision needs.

I have already read Apple's official accessibility page: http://www.apple.com/accessibility/osx/#vision

but it does not offer options to adjust colors or sizes of just some specific items.

If you know any ways or tools to adjust GUI item dimensions and colors without completely breaking application rendering, I would be really grateful for suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried changing the screen resolution, and increasing the contrast in the Accessibility preferences?

Comment: @IronCraftMan Thanks, it helps somewhat, but still not to the level of eye comfort I have used to have on Windows.